# When I want to run my j2ee+maven+spring-boot+mysql project on idea, there comes an error

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, maven, java-ee-8

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-06-23 22:33:08.783 ERROR 14944 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field recordRepository in com.myspring.demo.controller.MyController required a bean of type 'com.myspring.demo.Dao.RecordRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.myspring.demo.Dao.RecordRepository' in your configuration.
```

I have noticed that `com.myspring.demo.Dao.RecordRepository`,so I look for the code,and here is the code of Mycontroller.java

```
package com.myspring.demo.controller;

import com.myspring.demo.Dao.AppRepository;
import com.myspring.demo.Dao.RecordRepository;
import com.myspring.demo.Dao.StaffRepository;
import com.myspring.demo.entity.App;
import com.myspring.demo.entity.Record;
import com.myspring.demo.entity.Staff;
import com.myspring.demo.model.UsrSession;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/me")
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping("my")
    public String my(){
        return "my";
        }
    @RequestMapping("punch")
    public String punch(){
        return "punch";
    }
    @RequestMapping("check")
    public ModelAndView check(HttpSession httpSession){
        UsrSession usrSession= (UsrSession) httpSession.getAttribute("usr");
        int id=usrSession.getId();
        String currentMonth = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM").format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        List<Record>records=recordRepository.findAllByStaffId(id);
        List<Record>recordList=new ArrayList<>();
        if(!records.isEmpty()){
             for(Record r : records){
                String date=r.getDate();
                if(date.startsWith(currentMonth)){
                    recordList.add(r);
                }
            } 
        }
        ModelAndView modelAndView=new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("/check");
        modelAndView.addObject("records",recordList);
        return modelAndView;
    }
    @RequestMapping("/app")
    public String application(HttpServletRequest request,HttpSession httpSession){
        String recordid=request.getParameter("recordId");
        String reason=request.getParameter("reason");
        int id=Integer.parseInt(recordid);

        App app =new App();
        app.setExcuse(reason);
        app.setRecordId(id);
        UsrSession usrSession= (UsrSession) httpSession.getAttribute("usr");
        int staffid=usrSession.getId();
        int departid=staffRepository.findAllByStaffId(staffid).getDepartmentId();
        app.setStaffId(staffid);
        String currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new 
Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        app.setAppDay(currentDate);
        app.setState(0);
        app.setDepartmentId(departid);

        appRepository.save(app);
            return "my";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/confirm")
    public ModelAndView confirm(HttpServletRequest request,HttpSession httpSession){
        UsrSession usrSession= (UsrSession) httpSession.getAttribute("usr");
        if(usrSession.getType()==0) //员工
        {
            int id=usrSession.getId();
            List<App>apps=appRepository.findAllByStaffId(id);
            ModelAndView modelAndView=new ModelAndView();
            modelAndView.setViewName("/checkApp");
            modelAndView.addObject("apps",apps);
             return modelAndView;

        }
        else
        {
             int id=usrSession.getId();
            Staff s=staffRepository.findAllByStaffId(id);
            List<App>apps=appRepository.findAllByDepartmentId(s.getDepartmentId());
            ModelAndView modelAndView=new ModelAndView();
            modelAndView.setViewName("/confirmApp");
            modelAndView.addObject("apps",apps);
            return modelAndView;
        }
    }
    @RequestMapping("/modify")
    public String modify(HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request){
        String appId=request.getParameter("recordId");
        int aId=Integer.parseInt(appId);
        List<App>apps=appRepository.findAllByAppId(aId);
        if(!apps.isEmpty())
        {
            App app=apps.get(0);
            int rid=app.getRecordId()+1;
            List<Record>records=recordRepository.findAllByRecordId(rid);
           if(!records.isEmpty())
        {
            Record r= records.get(0);
            r.setState("ok");
            recordRepository.save(r);
        }
            apps.get(0).setState(1);
            appRepository.save(app);
        }
        return"my";
    }
    }
    @Autowired
    RecordRepository recordRepository;
    @Autowired
    AppRepository appRepository;
    @Autowired
    StaffRepository staffRepository;

}
```

it seems that the problem is coming at the last 6 lines.
and here is the RecordRepository.java

```
package com.myspring.demo.Dao;

import com.myspring.demo.entity.Record;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

public interface RecordRepository extends JpaRepository<Record,Integer> {
    public List<Record> findAllByStaffIdAndAndDate(Integer id,String date);
    public List<Record> findAllByStaffId(Integer id);
    public List<Record> findAllByRecordId(Integer id);
}
```

And this is the application.properties

```
server.port=8080
spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.http.encoding.force=true
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
server.tomcat.uri-encoding=UTF-8
```

And this is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.myspring</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.16</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- spring-boot-configuration-processor -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId> <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>application.properties</include>
            </includes>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

the img of project's struct[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R17UL.png)

Comment: Not sure if it's the problem, but can you try renaming your package `Dao` to `dao`, package must use lowercase convention. Since spring uses configurations by conventions... i wouldn't be surprised that it is not finding your repository

Comment: I have tried renaming Dao to dao, but the problem still exists.

Comment: First thing is you are mixing versions of spring-boot. One as parent 2.1.5.RELEASE and second 2.2.7.RELEASE for spring-boot-maven-plugin . Clean that up. Furthermore do not define quartz version cause spring-boot-parent already defines one version (Just use it without version).

Comment: In which packages are the spring boot main application defined? The controller and the repository?

Comment: I have put the img of the project's struct

Comment: is there anybody can help me？